# How to Write and Retrieve a Temporary Binary File With Node Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

## Issue

I am working with [Google Text To Speech (*TTS*)](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs) in order to save a generated binary audio file to [Google Cloud Storage (*GCS*)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration).

Saving a local binary file does not seem like a good idea in the Firebase's Cloud Functions environment. Therefore I'm looking **how to write and retrieve a temporary binary file?** When I attempt to retrieve the temporary file created currently I receive an error.

In the attempted solution below the temp file shows as being saved in the log, then I'm attempting to retrieve the temp file in the success portion of the file creation callback.

## Error

```
Error: Cannot parse JSON response  
at ApiError (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:43:9)
  at Util.parseHttpRespBody (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:167:42)
  at Util.handleResp (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:116:117)
  at retryRequest (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:403:22)
  at onResponse (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:200:7)
  at /user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:158:17
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

## Attempted Solution

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const projectId = 'coinverse-media-staging';
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: projectId,
});

const fs = require('fs');
const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');

const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();

admin.initializeApp();

const text = 'Hello, world!';

const request = {
   input: {text: text},
   // Select the language and SSML Voice Gender (optional)
   voice: {languageCode: 'en-US', ssmlGender: 'NEUTRAL'},
   // Select the type of audio encoding
   audioConfig: {audioEncoding: 'MP3'},
}; 

exports.getAudiocast = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

var bucket = storage.bucket('gs://[project-name].appspot.com/content/feeds/en-audio/');

client.synthesizeSpeech(request, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
      return;
    }

    const tempFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), (data.id + '.mp3'));

    fs.writeFile(tempFile, response.audioContent, 'binary', err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
        return;
      }

      console.log('Audio content written to file: ' + tempFile);

      bucket.upload(tempFile), function(err, file) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log('Audiocast uploaded!');
        } else {
          console.error('Audiocast upload error: ' + err.message);
        }
      };
    });  
});

return {
    filePath: "cloudStorage/someFilePath",
};
});
```

## Next Step

I will try uploading a normal text file instead of the binary file to see if the temporary file format is the issue.

Comment: This doesn't look like the name of a bucket, it looks like a URL to a file in storage: `gs://[project-name].appspot.com/content/feeds/en-audio/`.  It doesn't look to me like you're using the Cloud Storage API correctly.

Comment: [Storage Doc bucket](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/Bucket)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Doug_Stevenson and @AndersonMendes for the guidance!

## Solution

I was including both the **bucket** id to my *Google Cloud Storage* and the file path in the same string which was the source of the error.

### Bucket String

`var bucket = storage.bucket('gs://[projectName].appspot.com');`

### GCS Upload Method

```
bucket.upload(tempFile, { destination: ("directory/someFolderName/" + fileName) }, (err, file) => {
        if (!err) {
          console.log('Audiocast uploaded!');
        } else {
          console.error('Audiocast upload error: ' + err.message);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment due to lack of reputation points on this platform.

**You need to delete your temp files**:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#always_delete_temporary_files

Answer (score 0):

Same answer, my code:

```js
    const http = require('http');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    const os = require('os');

    var options = {
        destination: ('Audio/' + longLanguage + '/' + pronunciation + '/' + word + '.mp3'),
        contentType: 'audio/' + audioType
    };

    function oedPromise() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          const tempFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), (word + '.mp3'));
          const file = fs.createWriteStream(tempFile)
          http.get(apiURL, function(response) {
            response.pipe(file)
            .on('error', function(error) {
              console.error(error);
              reject(error);
            })
            .on('finish', function() {
              myBucket.upload(tempFile, options)
              .then(function(data) {
                return;
              })
              .catch(error => console.error(error));
            });
          });
        });
    }
```